# Javascript files not being read in node/ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have javascript that i'm trying to implement to create a hamburger menu when the screen is a specific size. But nothing happens.

Here is what my directory structure looks like:

```
public
    imgs
    javascript
        menu.js
    stylesheets
        style.css
        ...
routes
views
    partials
        ...
        nav.ejs
```

Here is the javascript:

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-btn')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("here")
})
```

Here is the nav bar ejs file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/nav.css">
<script src="/javascript/menu.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="title">
      <%= (typeof title !="undefined" ? title : "" ) %>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-btn">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item" href="/meals/new">ADD Meals</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item" href="/meals/index">ALL Meals</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

In my server.js file I have this code:

```
app.use(
  express.static(
    path.join(path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), 'public')
  )
)
```

With this it should be able to read the javascript files but nothing happens when I click on the menu. I don't see the console log. I have no issues using my stylesheets at all or the imgs files.

I found many posts that suggest changing the line in the server.js to this instead: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirnam, "public")));` but I was met with this error:

```
ReferenceError: __dirnam is not defined
    at file:///Users/.../code/projects/.../server.js:32:34
```

Any help offered would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's "dirname" not "dirnam"

Comment: @PavelZdenek Hello, I fixed it to __dirname and got this error: ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope. after a little bit of googling i was able to add these lines of code import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'; import { dirname } from 'path'; const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url); const __dirname = dirname(__filename); so my app doesnt crash anymore but the javascript still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It must be __dirname not __dirnam

Try:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Comment: Hello, I fix it to __dirname and got this error: ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope. after a little bit of googling i was able to add these lines of code 

import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

so my app doesnt crash anymore but the javascript still doesn't do anything.